# Using Thread Command to Solve Set of Linear Equations - Not Working

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a set of linear equations of the form

```
S.B = Bdiag.S                         (1)
```

where S, B are matrices and Bdiag is the diagonal matrix of B.

It was suggested to me to use the "Thread" command as one alternative to find the solution to equation (1) above. Note that I don't want to solve this using the eigenvectors, which I know how to do.

In any event, the code below comes "close" to the solution, but not quite. The reason is that after it runs, when I type in

```
S.B.Inverse[S]
```

should be equal to

```
Bdiag
```

but it's not as there is an extra lam in there (see below).

I am unclear because everything seems to be working "alright", but the answer is incorrect.

Thanks for your help...

Here is the code I have been using...

```
ClearAll[c1, c2, c3]
S = {{c1, -c2, 0}, {0, c3, -c1}, {0, 0, c2}};
B = {{lam, -lam, 0}, {0, lam + mu, -lam}, {0, 0, mu}};
Bdiag = DiagonalMatrix[{lam, lam + mu, lam}];

eqn = Thread[S.B == Bdiag.S];

eqn // ColumnForm;

eqs = Union@Flatten[Thread /@ eqn];
eqs // ColumnnForm

Out[256]= 
True, 
c2 lam == 0, 
c2 mu == c2 lam, 
-c3 lam - c1 mu == -c1 (lam + mu),
-c1 lam - c2 (lam + + mu) == -c2 lam

 Solve[{-c3 lam - c1 mu == -c1 (lam + mu),
        -c1 lam - c2 (lam + mu) == -c2 lam,
         c1 + c2 + c3 == 1}, {c1, c2, c3}] // FullSimplify

 Out[257]= {{c1 -> -(mu/(lam - 2 mu)), c2 -> lam/(lam - 2 mu), c3 -> -(mu/(lam - 2 mu))}}

 S = {{-(mu/(lam - 2 mu)), -(lam/(lam - 2 mu)), 0}, {0, -(mu/(lam - 2 mu)), -(mu/(lam - 2 mu))}, {0, 0, lam/(lam - 2 mu)}}

 S.B.Inverse[S] // FullSimplify

 {{lam, 0, lam}, {0, lam + mu, 2 mu}, {0, 0, mu}}
```

Comment: Why did you choose to discard two equations from `Solve`? Your solution is only correct if `lam==mu==0` ..   You can do `Reduce[eqs, {c1, c2, c3}]` and see your system only has a few trivial solutions.

Comment: aside you could simply do `Solve[ S.B == Bdiag.S  , {c1, c2, c3}]`. I cant follow what all that thread stuff is trying to accomplish, `Solve` handles a matrix equation just fine.